# Make a white label visible on top of bright image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**Basic issue:**

I believe the trick is with masking, but I am not able to get a good hold of how this is set.

Basically I have a bright image (set to a `uiimageview` object), and I have a label at very bottom (which is added on top of the image view) needs a well readable white text on it.  Right now, the white text is hard to read (because of the bright background).

**What I am doing:**

I am setting a mask for the image view with something like 
http://cl.ly/image/0i0N1p271d42

```
        maskContainer = [CALayer layer];
        UIImage *maskImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask_profile"];
        [maskContainer setContents:(id)[maskImg CGImage]];
        CGRect frma = maskContainer.frame;
        frma.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
        frma.size.height = self.frame.size.height;
        maskContainer.frame = frma;
    [self.imageView.layer setMask:maskContainer];
```

Its messed up. The overall image starts fading on top.

Can anyone share their insight on the right way to mask?

Comment: maskContainer's frame should be the same as label's frame.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set the label's background color to a partially transparent black color?

Comment: This will not work out.

Comment: Why not? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a drop shadow on your text to make is stand out even over a white background:

```
myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8f;
myLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option is to adjust the alpha on the UILabel to the desired darkness in order to make the text stand out. If you do not want to hide the image and the image itself serves as a dark background, then set the alpha on the label to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to place the label in a uiview then create a gradient to apply as the background to the uiview. You can create the gradient as either an image with transparency or you can draw it in code. This will create a darkening effect on you bright image just behind the label so the text will pop.

Comment: Yeah, thats the deal with using a mask right. Setting that gradient as a mask. I am trying to see how that is feasible. Need to dig further.

Comment: @Legolas No need to create a mask, just subclass a `UIView` to apply the gradient to the background.